# passing multiple parameters to deploy script (ethers, upgrades)

Tags: constructor, proxy-contracts, hardhat-deploy, local-variables

I'm looking for the tutorial or instruction manual for parameter syntax

My solidity file has the following initializer:

```
function initialize(
      address addy,
      string memory _var1,
      string memory _var2,
      string memory _var3,
      address[] memory _varArray,
      address _var4,
      uint128 _var5,
) external initializer {
```

and my deploy script has `await upgrades.deployProxy(MyCustomContract, );` with I presume the second parameter takes an array of method variables. Every example I've seen online has shown only a single variable passed in through square brackets, such as `[42]`

What is the syntax for passing in multiple variables, some of which are arrays themselves? What is the "null" or no variable syntax if I don't have a specific thing to pass

Comment: Take a look at how I implemented this [here](https://github.com/hifi-finance/hifi/blob/37fb1b31bf2385f1f458afa5a2df6d17c7dfa69b/packages/protocol/tasks/deploy/balanceSheet.ts#L20-L22).

Comment: `[123, "abc", [1,2,3] , ["cat", "dog"], "https://...", 42]`

Comment: @sola24 that's very helpful thanks! I wasn't sure if addresses needed quotes or not as well